# How to debugging on runtime using Python extension on vscode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

First of all, I have started using react+python for my learning and progress. I am from .Net MVC background and very much into how visual studio provide debugging in dev environment. but, here I am bit confused with the same part. I am using vscode with python extension as suggested in official thread [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial). The project runs fine `using uvicorn main:app --reload` but I can't debug the code here as it never go back to vs code.

here is my project structure:

```
LearningPy <folder name>  
    |-- apis <folder name>     
         |--modelservice <folder name>  
             |--dataprovider.py  
             |--persondetails.py
             |--examtemplate.py  
         |--main.py    
         |--config.py
```

Here is my main.py:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from datetime import datetime

from apis import config
from apis.modelservice import dataprovider,examtemplate

app = FastAPI(debug=True)
def get_application() -> FastAPI:
    application = FastAPI(title="PersonProfile", description="Learning Python CRUD",version="0.1.0")
    origins = [
        config.API_CONFIG["origin_local_ip"],
        config.API_CONFIG["origin_local_url"]
    ]
    application.add_middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=origins,
        allow_credentials=True,
        allow_methods=["*"],
        allow_headers=["*"],
    )
    #application.include_router(processA.router)
    return application

app = get_application()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"main": "API Server " + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")}

@app.get("/dbcheck")
def read_root():
    try:
        dataprovider.get_db().get_collection("Person")
    except Exception as e:
        return {"failed":e}
    else:
        return { "connected":True}

 @app.post("/upload")
 def read_excel():    
    try:   
    #call here from readexcel.py
        examtemplate.read_excel_data()
    except Exception as e:
            return {"failed":e}
```

reason behind understanding above question:

If I write all code in one page then it runs fine and I get the output, but when I use folder structure then It doesnt work expected.

Let me know what I am missing.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this in the "launch.json":

```
"env": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
       },
```

Explanation:
The python interpreter can't find 'apis' package, because 'LearningPy' is not in the [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonpath#envvar-PYTHONPATH) variable, this causes these statements get errors:

```
from apis import config
from apis.modelservice import dataprovider,examtemplate
```